# Can I stop std::cout flushing on "\n"?

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio, io-buffering

According to to [this post](http://www.cpptalk.net/n-and-flush-cout-vt9984.html) std::cout will automatically flush on `\n` when it is attached to an interactive device (e.g. a terminal window).  Otherwise (e.g. when being piped to a file) it will act fully buffered and will only flush on `.flush()` or `std::endl`.

Is there a way to override this behaviour in Microsoft Visual C++ so that I can select whether I want fully buffered or line buffered mode?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful, I doubt it helps you much with your problem though. http://nibuthomas.com/2009/02/12/writing-endl-like-functions-for-output-streams/

Comment: It seems there is some debate as to the legitimacy of the claim that C++ incorporates the C90 line-buffered vs fully-buffered distinction for std::cout.  Regardless, is there a way to change between buffering modes with MSVC?

Comment: Maybe you could write a test program and see if the claim is true?

Answer (score 14):

Contrary to anon's (Apr 28 '09) answer, this behavior has nothing to do with the operating system or "console software."

C++'s `<iostream>` streams are designed to be interoperable with C's `<stdio.h>` streams. The goal is to allow uses of `std::cout` to be intermixed with uses of `printf`/`puts`. To achieve this, `std::cout`'s `streambuf` is implemented atop C's `stdout` stream. It is actually C's `stdout` that is line-buffered when the standard output is attached to a terminal device.

You can call [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) (before your program uses any of C++'s standard I/O streams) to tell the C++ streams library to communicate directly with the underlying file descriptors rather than layering atop C's streams library. This avoids C's `stdout` stream entirely and speeds up C++'s I/O streams at the cost of the two libraries no longer mixing well.

An alternative is to unconditionally set `stdout` to fully buffered by calling [`std::setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf). Then, even though `std::cout` is still writing through `stdout`, you will not have `stdout` flushing after every newline.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with C++ (there is no language requirement that \n flushes anything) but with your operating system and/or console software. If the console wants to flush its buffer when it sees a newline, then it can, and I would guess that most do so. Note that it is important to differentiate between the C++ runtime's buffers (which can be to some extent controlled from your C++ code) and the buffers of the console application (over which it has no control).

FYI, there is a flag in the standard iostream library called **unitbuf** which if set causes the buffers to be flushed after each output operation. It is set, for example, for the std::cerr stream.  This has nothing to do with the '\n' character however, as you can output multiple '\n' s in a single operation.

Comment: From the page I linked to: "If standard output is or may be attached to an interactive device, it is line-buffered; otherwise it is fully buffered. (C99 specifies this in section 7.19.3 paragraph 7; I believe C90 says the same, and C++98 incorporates C90 by reference.)"  Do you believe this to be wrong?

Comment: I don't have access to the C Standard documents, so can't really comment. However, the C++ Standard does NOT incorporate the C Standard, by reference or otherwise. The C++ Standard refers to the C standard in specific cases.

Comment: @pauldoo: I've heard that claim about C++ incorporating C before, but as far as I know, it only refers to specific sections. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I'm afraid the only reference I have is the forum post I linked to in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation is free to flush whenever it feels it is appropriate. It varies from vendor to vendor whether they flush on `\n` or not.

I can see something called `ios_base& nounitbuf(ios_base& str);` from my C++0x draft. Give it a shot. This is about the only thing that standard C++ gives you.

Comment: Hm, I wasn't sure so I had mentioned the draft.

Comment: However, diligent research indicates there is a stream flag "unitbuf" setting this should flush the stream after each operation. I'll update my answer to reflect this.