# Tell `endl` not to flush

Tags: c++, newline, iostream

My program prints a large number of short lines to `cout`.

As a slightly contrived example, my lines look a little like this:

```
cout<<"The variable's value is: "<<variable<<endl;
```

I'd like the program to run *fast* and I do believe that `endl` is killing me because it initiates a buffer flush on `cout` every time it is used.

Now, some folks on the internet have said that I could do this instead:

```
cout<<"The variable's value is: "<<variable<<"\n";
```

But this does not seem like a good solution because `endl` abstracts the particular system-specific ways an end line might be specified, where as `\n` does not. This also seems like a poor solution because, should I need buffering in the future, I would then have to modify the whole code base.

Therefore, I ask, is there a way to disable the buffer-flushing aspect of `endl`?

**EDIT**

Further digging *seems* to indicate that both `endl` and `\n` respect the various ways an OS might choose to end it's lines. [It also seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796865/can-i-stop-stdcout-flushing-on-n) that the output stream detects if it's in a potentially interactive situation and buffers and flushes accordingly. Therefore: the problem may be solved by manually telling the output stream to perform aggressive buffering... if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - endl and flushing the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751972/c-endl-and-flushing-the-buffer)

Comment: Important to note that this is OS/terminal specific.  There is nothing in the spec which requires a flush on newline.

Comment: @ling.s: I fail to see how this question is a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I suspect that `cout`, by writing to `stdout`, will implicitly be opened in text mode and therefore do the character conversion necessary to convert `\n` to the right line ending. I can't find anything confirming this, though, but I suspect that writing `\n` is totally fine and portable.

Comment: Just curious... if you're writing that many lines quickly... how can the user even read them?  What's the point?  stdout is line buffered because it's assumed to be _interactive_. If it's not then why not simply write somewhere else?

Comment: @EdS., the user may not be able to read individual lines, but the user can see patterns and trends in large numbers of lines.

Comment: @Ed The standard does not require a flush on '\n'. But it does on `endl`. This is not OS specific.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/213977/1411457

Comment: @AlanStokes: Yes, I know that. I was referring to the newline suggestion.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796865/can-i-stop-stdcout-flushing-on-n) may, however, be a duplicate.

Comment: And the rabbit whole goes [deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857052/why-is-printing-to-stdout-so-slow-can-it-be-sped-up).

Comment: Problem can be solved by avoiding using `std::ostream` period.

Comment: "I do believe that endl is killing me" you should measure rather than believe, you may be surprised.

Answer (score 10):

> endl abstracts the particular system-specific ways an end line might be specified, where as \n does not".

`std::endl` is defined to output `'\n'` followed by a flush. The correct abstraction of the system-specific newline thingy is just `'\n'`.

To prevent flushes, one just doesn't use `std::endl`. In addition, the standard output may be line-buffered if it is or may be connected to an interactive device, in this case the newline character will flush the stream. If that's an issue, use an `ofstream` connected to a named file. I think on Unix-like systems line buffering only happens when the standard output is a terminal.

Comment: That's not really the question though.  he wants to prevent flushes.  Many platforms will also flush if they see a newline.

Comment: It seems to me this exactly answers  the question. You avoid the flush by just writing '\n', and you don't lose any portability.

Comment: @AlanStokes: There is no guarantee that a newline won't cause a flush.  I did miss what he was getting at at first glance though. I can't find any bullet proof way to do this. Maybe write to `cerr` instead?  Hackish, but....

Comment: @Ed And no reason why it would. But *that* wasn't the question. And as it happens `cerr` flushes after every write.

Comment: @AlanStokes, "In many implementations, standard output is line-buffered, and writing '\n' causes a flush anyway" -- [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl).

Comment: @AlanStokes: Of course it is.  "Performance is poor due to constant flushing of the output stream, how can I fix this?"  I think it's reasonable to assume that he doesn't want a "solution" which may or may not work given the user's environment.

Comment: @EdS.: fair point regarding what was asked for - but FWIW most programs print to stdout without explicit flushing, and if the *terminal* happens to flush per line then it's rarely a problem as particularly long output is typically piped or redirected, e.g. to less, tail, a file, /dev/null etc..

Comment: @TonyD: Agreed.  I asked him in the comments if he really needed/wanted to throw so much data at the user.

Answer (score 7):

`endl` flushes. If you don't want that behaviour, don't use `endl`. If you want to change your code easily, use your own manipulator:

```
inline std::ostream& myendl( std::ostream& os ){
    os.put(os.widen('\n'));
    return os;
}
```

That way you can easily change the behaviour of your `myendl` at one place.

Comment: The `os.widen()` isn't needed as the character type is known.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

endl:: Inserts a endline character into the output sequence os and flushes it as if by calling `os.put(os.widen('\n'))` followed by `os.flush()`.

So it appears you want to just write `os.put(os.widen('\n'))`, which should, from this definition be safe and portable and correct, as well as meeting your primary needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is std::nounitbuf which is documented to have some effect in this matter.
However, I didn't notice any difference. To bypass all of the ostream's ideas of when or when not to flush I tried this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
//  std::cout << std::nounitbuf;
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ){
//  std::cout <<  "Test " << "file" << '\n';
    oss <<  "Test " << "file" << '\n';
}
std::cout << oss.str();
```

This improved execution time from ~33 sec to ~25csec.

IF your output goes to an xterm, your execution speed is severly limited by xterm's work to do scrolling etc. If you use a pipeline to filter out unnecessary lines you'll see a dramatic increase in speed, e.g.

```
./program | grep -v "The variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

If flushing is the problem, you can implement a stream buffer that overrides the `sync()` member function to only flush to the external device if you specify so. It also obligates creating your own manipulators `flush_on_endl` and `noflush_on_endl` if you intend to change these preferences throughout the program.

```
#include <iostream>

static int disable() {
    static int index(std::ios_base::xalloc());
    return index;
}

class save_buffer
{
public:
    save_buffer(std::ios& other)
        : str(other), buf(other.rdbuf())
    { }

    ~save_buffer() { str.rdbuf(buf); }
private:
    std::ios& str;
    std::streambuf* buf;
};

class syncing_buffer_optional : public std::streambuf, private save_buffer
{
public:
    syncing_buffer_optional(std::ostream& other)
        : save_buffer(other),
          buf(other.rdbuf()),
          disable_sync(other.iword(disable()))
    { }

    std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c)
    {
        buf->sputc(c);
        return 0;
    }

    int sync()
    {
        return disable_sync? 0: buf->pubsync();
    }
private:
    std::streambuf* buf;
    bool disable_sync;
};

std::ostream& flush_on_endl(std::ostream& os)
{
    os.iword(disable()) = false;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& noflush_on_endl(std::ostream& os)
{
    os.iword(disable()) = true;
    return os;
}


std::ostream& endl(std::ostream& os)
{
    syncing_buffer_optional eb(os);
    os.rdbuf(&eb);

    return os << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << noflush_on_endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note: I needed to create an `endl` function because of the lifetime dependencies between the buffer and the stream. Moreover, even if the buffer was static, how can we distinguish between an `std::endl` call and an arbitrary `flush()`?