# Why buffer is always automatically flushed?

Tags: c++, output, flush

I had searched for "buffer" in c++ quite a lot before I ask it here, all answers I got were "buffer in C++ will not be flushed automatically unless a specific statement like `std::flush` or `std::endl` is specified.  However, I found that the buffer is always automatically flushed in my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i;
    cout << "begin...\n";
    for (i = 0; i<1000000000; i++);
    cout << "end" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What I got is "begin..." and a new line (\n) were shown first. Then after a few seconds, "end" is shown. Does that mean the buffer was flushed after

```
cout << "begin...\n";
```

Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You have a `\n` at the end of the "begin" string. couting an `\n` is the same as couting an `endl`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/213977/4117728) says something different. I also always thought that `endl` puts a new line and flushes while `\n` only puts a new line

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796865/can-i-stop-stdcout-flushing-on-n

Comment: @NathanOliver but I have tried both contain \n and without, and both of the results were different from what I expected.

Comment: I think this might be the most related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430701/does-new-line-character-also-flush-the-buffer

Comment: @MichaelWalz is it? but I got the same result even if I remove the \n, also isn't \n and endl different when we talking about buffer?

Comment: The dupe is almost the same question. And answer is what i guessed, but wasnt sure: The implementation may flush the stream whenever it likes.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand, "buffer can (most likely) be automatically flushed anytime in a normal computer", is it?

Comment: Oh, I got it, but I am now curious about why there isn't a formal/clear explanation of the buffer flushing, anyway, thanks all of youXD