# Unexpected behavior using std::map with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

So I need a thread pool for my application, which led me to create a `std::map<int, std::thread>` object.
I've encountered some very unexpected behavior, which can be simplified to this:

```cpp
std::map<int, std::thread> threads;

threads.insert(std::pair<int, std::thread>(1, std::thread([]() {
        std::cout << "I'm the first thread and I'm gonna work\n";
    })));
threads[1].join();

std::cout << "Thread 1 joinable? " << threads[1].joinable() << "\n";

threads.insert(std::pair<int, std::thread>(1, std::thread([]() {
        std::cout << "I'm not gonna work at all\n";
    })));
threads[1].join();
```

The output is

```
I'm the first thread and I'm gonna work
Thread 1 joinable? 0
```

Right after, `std::terminate()` is called and program receives SIGABRT signal.

Live debugging suggested that `terminate` is being called because `joinable()` is true, but I just checked and figured it's not!

Moreover, the way to overcome it was simply to add the following line after `join()`ing:

```
threads.erase(1);
```

That leaves me a bit confused, as it looks like a new instance of `std::thread` was created just before my `insert` call... Can someone hint me about this unexpected behavior?

Comment: When you trace on stdout, don't forget to flush.

Comment: @molbdnilo - Newlines ought to do that.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `'\n'` does not flush `std::cout`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - That's news to me :/  (At least in a world where cout wraps stdout in a typical environment.)  Can you clarify?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: `\n` causes `std::cout` to flush if it's connected directly to a terminal, but not otherwise.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/796865/845092

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yup (I guess that's what I lazily meant by "typical environment", but fair enough!)

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth std::endl  do force flushing.. \n wouldn't flush every terminal even, that's platform-dependent (it's terminal functionality to flush the stream on receiving \n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert :

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

Your map already contains an element at key `1` so the second `threads.insert` doesn't do anything. You are simply trying to join twice on the same `std::thread`. This is why `threads.erase(1);` solves the problem, your map no longer contains a thread at key `1`.

Comment: Great, thank you. So there is no straightforward API for overriding an existing key, am I right?

Comment: @OmerPerry `treads[1] = std::thread( [](){ /* do work*/ } );` will "overwrite" the thread at key `1` with a new one. There is no method for deleting then replacing an element in a single call, however move assignment should do the same thing for any movable type.